# ASP.NET MVC 4 over-eager client side validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I have a form on a View where I allow user to enter some data and submit using a button.
I am using DataAnnotations on the Model to hook server and client side validation on the data. Correct validation scripts ("~/Scripts/jquery.validate*") have been included in the form.

Now the problem is that on all the fields, validation kicks in as soon as I start typing in (onkeyup) which is not desirable straightaway. I want the user to type their input, tab-out (onblur), and then display the error (say, RegularExpression error). And when they come back to the specific input control and start typing, show the validation error on keyup and blur both. A separate form on a different project does exactly that, and I can see no difference in the Model or view (or even the source created at the end).

I could disable the onkeyup using 'validator.settings.onkeyup = false;' and probably hook it up later - all using javascript. But the other project does it without this.

**Working as desired:**

Model field:

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name Required")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Must be under 50 characters")]
    [RegularExpression(@"\b(^[A-Za-z][\w\-'\s\.]{0,49})", ErrorMessage = "Valid Name required")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
```

View:

```
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DetailsModel.Name, new { placeholder = "Name", @class = "form-control" })
    <span class="hidden-desktop"></span>
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.DetailsModel.Name, "", new { @class = "AlertText" })
```

**Over Eager validation (the one with the problem):**

Model field:

```
    [DisplayName("Name of Officer")]
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Must be under 100 characters")]
    [RegularExpression(@"\b([\w\-'\s]{1,100})\b", ErrorMessage = "Please put in a valid Name")]
    public string OfficerName { get; set; }
```

View:

```
     @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.OfficerName)
     @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.OfficerName, new { placeholder = "Officer Name", @class = "form-control" })
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.OfficerName)
```

I looked at this link to figure out how client validation works : http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/adding-validation-to-the-model (see portion where author talks about **Validation Error UI in ASP.NET MVC** and lists steps to kick the validation.

Also, both these are partial views. One of them is displayed as a result of an Ajax call and the other one is displayed using 'EditorForModel'.

Has anyone seen/solved this sort of problem? Would really appreciate your help with this.

**Edit**:

HTML for the Working control:

```
<input class="form-control"  data-val="true"
data-val-regex="Valid Name required"
data-val-regex-pattern="\b(^[A-Za-z][\w\-'\s\.]{0,49})"
data-val-length="Must be under 50 characters"
data-val-length-max="50"
data-val-required="Name Required"
id="DetailsModel_Name"  name="DetailsModel.Name"
placeholder="Name"  type="text"  value=""  maxlength="50">
```

HTML for the problematic control:

```
<input class="form-control"  data-val="true"
data-val-regex="Please put in a valid Name"
data-val-regex-pattern="\b([\w\-'\s]{1,100})\b"
data-val-length="Must be under 100 characters"
data-val-length-max="100"
data-val-required="The Name of Officer field is required."
id="OfficerName" name="OfficerName"
placeholder="Name" type="text" value="">
```

Comment: Remove reference to JQUERY unobstrusive validation file, you will get the desired output